# Kак распарсить CSV файл в DataFrame?

Tags: python, парсер, pandas, dataframe, csv

Есть [CSV файл](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1YScoIGdphGDznwRJbIqPnwHVQIAz8B0r)):

```
df = pd.read_csv(data3, sep=" ", header=None)
```

Парсится в одну колонку, а надо в 4 колонки DataFrame.

Как сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [43]: df = pd.read_csv(filename, sep=";", header=None)
# NOTE: --------------------------> ^^^^^^^

In [44]: df
Out[44]:
              0    1   2       3
0    07.01.2017  337   0     0.0
1    07.03.2017  334   3    77.4
2    07.04.2017  303  31   863.4
3    07.05.2017  253  50  1370.0
4    07.06.2017  250   3    82.2
..          ...  ...  ..     ...
541  25.12.2019   87   8   232.0
542  26.12.2019   85   2    54.0
543  30.12.2019   71  14   300.0
544  01.09.2020   25  46  1334.0
545  01.10.2020   23   2    38.0

[546 rows x 4 columns]
```

---

Если нужно парсить даты:

```
In [45]: df = pd.read_csv(filename, sep=";", header=None, parse_dates=[0], dayfirst=True)

In [46]: df
Out[46]:
             0    1   2       3
0   2017-01-07  337   0     0.0
1   2017-03-07  334   3    77.4
2   2017-04-07  303  31   863.4
3   2017-05-07  253  50  1370.0
4   2017-06-07  250   3    82.2
..         ...  ...  ..     ...
541 2019-12-25   87   8   232.0
542 2019-12-26   85   2    54.0
543 2019-12-30   71  14   300.0
544 2020-09-01   25  46  1334.0
545 2020-10-01   23   2    38.0

[546 rows x 4 columns]

In [47]: df.dtypes
Out[47]:
0    datetime64[ns]
1             int64
2             int64
3           float64
dtype: object
```

Comment: Спасибо, ";" не догадалась поставить, делала ведь и забыла